# Why is a Range apparently an Array?

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel VBA the function

```
IsArray(Range("A1:A5"))
```

will return `True` for any range containing more than one cell (as far as I can tell).

Why is this? The same is not true other iterable objects like `Collection` and `ArrayList`. And how can I modify my array checking code to return `True` solely for arrays, not array-like objects?

Comment: The default property is `Value`. It will be an array unless it consists of one cell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `Range` is an object.

```
Debug.Print TypeName(Range("A1:A5")) ' prints "Range"
```

What you're doing is an *implicit default member call*, invoking `Range.[_Default]`, which boils down to invoking `Range.Value`, ...which returns a 2D array given any **multiple-cell** range.

[image: object browser showing hidden default member of Excel.Range]

```
Debug.Print IsArray(Range("A1").Value)    ' prints "False"
Debug.Print IsArray(Range("A1:A2").Value) ' prints "True"
```

That default member call is made "behind your back" because VBA is "being helpful" and, seeing that you're invoking `IsArray(someObjectReference)`, goes to the interface of that `someObjectReference`, sees that there's a default member for it, and evaluates `IsArray(someObjectReference.DefaultMember)` instead of `IsArray(someObjectReference)`, which wouldn't be useful (an object reference *obviously* isn't an array... right?).

You get similar results with other classes/types that expose a *default member*. Is `Application` a `String`?

```
Debug.Print Application ' prints "Microsoft Excel"
```

[image: object browser showing hidden default member of Excel.Application]

Of course not - it's an object, but with a default member that, when invoked, boils down to invoking its `Name` property getter.

When assigning an object reference, the `Set` keyword is required:

```
Dim foo As Variant
Set foo = Range("A1")
```

Without the `Set` keyword, the same code would be assigning to the returned object's *default member*:

```
Dim foo As Variant
foo = Range("A1") '.Value is implicit
```

Write code that *says what it does, and does what it says* - avoid implicit default member calls where possible.

Comment: Worth adding maybe - default properties in VBA are why `Set` exists: to distinguish between asking for an object itself vs. its default property. In contrast, VB.NET has no default properties, and hence no `Set` keyword.

Comment: ++ nicely explained :) Also `...The same is not true other iterable objects like Collection and ArrayList...` Array is more like a cupboard/almirah where you keep clothes. the Dimensions are either fixed or are set at runtime dynamically. The size of the array doesn't increase automatically like it does in collections/dictionaries/arraylist.

Comment: @Siddharth a `Collection` having a parameterized `Item` default member is also probably contributing to the OP's confusion; it being parameterized makes it somewhat harder to accidentally invoke... even though one could conceivably spend years writing `foo(i)` without realizing they're really doing `foo.Item(i)` (and not realizing a `Collection` iterated by index is inefficient, but that's another discussion!)

Comment: Thanks, that was really thorough. So I suppose in order to identify a plain array, I should use `IsArray` in combination with `Not IsObject` as only objects can have default members? Or are there some weird non-object types that will also return `True` for `IsArray`. Alternatively, is there any way to tell VBA to ignore the default member, some fancy trick with `VarPtr` perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `TypeOf` functionality to determined this:

```
Function arrayIsRange(arr As Variant) As Boolean
    arrayIsRange = TypeOf arr Is Excel.Range
End Function
```

In use:

```
Sub test()
    'prints "True"
    Debug.Print arrayIsRange(Range("A1:C3"))


    arr = Array(1, 2, 3)
    'prints "False"
    Debug.Print arrayIsRange(arr)
End Sub
```