# how to avoid the last empty field in the list of combobox

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new at vba and I'm trying to create a form that contains a list of items from another excel book.

This is the table saved in another excel book where I want to take the data:
[image]

I need my combobox take items from the range("C2") which takes as 1st item "Petronor" until it find the 1st blank in the row.

I made this:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim archivo As Workbook
    Dim i As Long
    Set archivo = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\se72497\Desktop\Departamentos.xlsx")

    For i = 2 To archivo.Sheets("Hoja1").Range("C2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Row
        ComboBox1.AddItem archivo.Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(i, 3).Value
    Next i

    archivo.Close
End Sub
```

1) 1st at all I create a variable that contains the file where I want take data:

```
 Dim archivo As Workbook
 Set archivo = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\se72497\Desktop\Departamentos.xlsx")
```

2) After that with a loop For Next I tried the code to go through all the items from the range("C2") until the 1st blank in that row. I have to say this code I made it from another I saw and I'm still trying to uderstand how this work because I'm not sure at all althought I know about all the properties that are used. I'm confused about the property range.row because I don't know how it works. I hope someone can explain me that too.

```
 Dim i As Long
 For i = 2 To archivo.Sheets("Hoja1").Range("C2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Row
        ComboBox1.AddItem archivo.Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(i, 3).Value
 Next i
```

3) Finally I added a piece of code to close the file I opened before:

```
archivo.Close
```

The problem of this code is that I get a blank in the last field of combobox as this:
[image]

Please help me to solve this issue and I'm open to hear improvements on the code.

Comment: Remove `.Offset(1, 0)`, that "go down one cell" is what's making your list include one too many items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always better to work up from the bottom of the sheet rather than down (particularly if you have nothing after C2; your Offset was taking in the final blank cell too), and you can avoid a loop by using `List`:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    ComboBox1.List = Range("C2", .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Can anyone explain why the `Value` is needed?

Comment: :-) Possibly helpful to answer the question why the `.List` property fails in interpreting a *pure* `Range` reference as a 2-dim variant array: [Why is a range apparently an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715543/why-is-a-range-apparently-an-array/51715656#51715656), *answered by Mathieu Guindon*

Comment: It's worth mentioning that assigning a 2-dim (variant) array to a combobox or listbox overcomes the built-in limitation of the `.AddItem` method to **10** columns only.

Answer (score 0):

I would get the count of the number of rows, instead of using the range -something like

```
Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
```

Then in your for loop

```
For i = 2 To lastRow
```